# Intuitive integration of $rect(t)-rect(t-1)$

Tags: integration, education

How can I integrate the function (http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=rect(t)-rect(t-1) ):

$$rect(t)-rect(t-1)$$

in an intuitive way, or without using heaviside function? Until -0.5 the integral is 0, after I have a straight line $t$ until 0.5 and after?

Thank you very much.

Comment: It might be helpful if, in addition to linking to Wolfram|Alpha, you also defined the $\mathrm{rect}$ function in your question.  It would provide some helpful context.

Comment: Hi @XanderHenderson $rect(t)$ is a rectagle with width 1, with centre in $0$, with unit amplitude. It can be express as algebric sum of two heaviside functions (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangular_function please).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Wolfram Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RectangleFunction.html), the "rect" function $\Pi$ is defined by
$$
\Pi(t) := \begin{cases}
1 & \text{if $|t|<\frac{1}{2}$}, \\
\frac{1}{2} & \text{if $|t| = \frac{1}{2}$, and} \\
0 & \text{if $|t| > \frac{1}{2}$.}
\end{cases}
$$
This actually makes it very easy to integrate, if you keep in mind that the integral represents the (signed) area bounded between the curve, the limits of integration, and the horizontal axis.

With $f(t) := \Pi(t) - \Pi(t-1)$, the integral of $f$ is always going to represent the area of a rectangle, or the sum of the areas of two rectangles.  For example,
$$ \int_{0}^{2} f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t $$
is the area under the first bump, bounded on the left by the line $x=0$, and above the second bump.  The area under the first bump is a rectangle with width $\frac{1}{2}$ and height 1, hence it has area $\frac{1}{2}$.  The area above the second graph is a rectangle with width 1 and height $-1$, hence it has area $-1$.  Thus
$$ \int_{0}^{2} f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t = \frac{1}{2} - 1 = -\frac{1}{2}.$$
Visually, this looks like

[image]

The Desmos worksheet from which that image was created can be found [this link](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/glgclzxgpb).

Comment: How can I write the antiderivative of a definite integral? In this way I can know the value of area in each time.

Comment: It isn't too hard to deduce the form of the antiderivative.  On the interval $(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$, it is a line with slope 1, on the interval $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2})$, it is a line with slope $-1$, and it is constant everywhere else.  Like the function itself, an antiderivative will be piecewise defined (though you could phrase at least part of it in terms of the absolute value function). See here for an example: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/wrgxiqfaeu .